# I have unmatched values (Diff between df1 to df2) and I wanted to convert them into list

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have used the below logic to get the diff values between df1 to df2. Below are the output.

```
**row, cols = np.where(comparison_values == False)
  for item in zip(row, cols):
      df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]] = "{}-->{}".format(df1.iloc[item[0],item[1]],df2.iloc[item[0],item[1]])
      
  print(diff_values)
  print(type(diff_values))**

Actual output:
Shanna --> Ramesh
clarence.powers@gmail.com --> ramesh@gmail.com
Austin --> Estin
PA --> US
<class 'str'>
```

I wanted to convert the above output into list, so once we get the list i will upload the data into xlsx using xlsxwriter with color.
Could anyone please help me on this, i am new to python.

```
Required Output:
['Shanna --> Ramesh','clarence.powers@gmail.com --> ramesh@gmail.com','Austin 
--> Estin','PA --> US']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
print(diff_values.split("\n"))

# Output
['Shanna --> Ramesh', 'clarence.powers@gmail.com --> ramesh@gmail.com', 'Austin --> Estin', 'PA --> US']
```

Comment: Thanks Laurent for the quick response, I tried the above logic, but the output is coming like below. output: ['Shanna --> Ramesh']                                         
                       ['clarence.powers@gmail.com --> ramesh.yatham@gmail.com']          
                       ['Austin --> Yatham']                                                                                    
                       ['PA --> US'] this is not my expected output.

Comment: Ok. You're printing `diff_value` but your code doesn't show where it comes from, could you complete it? Also, is the print statement outside the for loop or in it? In which case, could you correct the indentation of your code?